# Why is ng-repeat one time binding not working in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

After doing most of my testing in Chrome, I have discovered my site is running like a dog in IE 11

After some investigation I am trying to use one time binding on my ng-repeats, however when I use the double colon syntax nothing renders on my page

Here is a snippet

```
<div data-ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">
    <div id="Raiders{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="player in ::players | filter:{ Team:'Raiders', Group: $index + 1}">
        <div style="white-space:nowrap">
            <span ng-click="updateTeam(player)">{{::player.FullName}}</span>
            <span class="statsFootball" ng-click="showTabDialog(player)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My only change has been to use :: (double colon) in my ng-repeat statement and also to print `player.FullName`

I am using Angular 1.5.8

I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe the `players` is not set at the moment of rendering.

Comment: Remove double colon in ng repeat and try once